# How to dynamicaly set up unique id to objects in js?

Tags: javascript, html, .net, web-applications

Writing a project in .Net and having trouble with js.

I need a method to trigger a click on the 'generate' button that takes data from the (dropdown menu) after the click.

I have a button 'btn', when I click on it the page loads an image with a 'dropdown' button. I need to take data from the dropdown menu(n, size, url) when I click on the button 'Dropdown' to use it later but the onclick method only reads the values of the first button. I tried to create a method to create unique button id but it doesn't work, all buttons have the same id.

```
var i = 0;
$('.dropdown').each(function () {
    i++;
    var newID = 'VarBtn' + i;
    $(this).attr('id', newID);
});

$(document).ready(() =>
{
    $('#btn').click(function ()
    {
        var input = {};
        input.n = parseInt($('#quantity').val());
        input.prompt = $('#txt').val();
        input.size = $('#sel').find(":selected").val();
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Home/GenerateImage',
            method: 'post',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            data: JSON.stringify(input)            

        }).done(function (data) {
            $.each(data.data, function () {
                $('#display').append(                    
                    '<div class="col-md-3 p-10" style="padding-top:10px">' +
                    '<div class="dropdown">' +
                    '<button class="btnV" id="idOne">Dropdown</button>' +
                    '<div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">' +
                    '<br>Select size' +
                    '<select id="Vsel">' +
                    '<option selected>256x256</option>' +
                    '<option>512x512</option>' +
                    '<option>1024x1024</option>' +
                    '</select>' +
                    '<br>Enter quantity' +
                    '<input type="number" id="Vquantity" value="1" min="1" max="10" />' +
                    '<br>' +
                    '<button id="VarBtn_'+i+ '" >Generate</button>' +
                    '</div>' +
                    '</div>' +
                    '<img class="p-10" id="GenImg" src = "' + this.url + '">' +
                    '</div>');
            });
        });
    });

$(document.body).on('click', '#VarBtn', function () {
   //Code..  
});
```

I tried to make unique id's for the buttons, so that clicking on the 'VarBtn' button will access the desired button and take the necessary data by unique id from the dropdown menu, but all id's remain the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
var i = 0;
$('.dropdown').each(function () {
    i++;
    var newID = 'VarBtn' + i;
    $(this).attr('id', newID);
});

$(document).ready(() =>
{
    $('#btn').click(function ()
    {
        var input = {};
        input.n = parseInt($('#quantity').val());
        input.prompt = $('#txt').val();
        input.size = $('#sel').find(":selected").val();
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Home/GenerateImage',
            method: 'post',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            data: JSON.stringify(input)            

        }).done(function (data) {
            $.each(data.data, function () {
                var btnID = 'VarBtn_' + i;
                $('#display').append(                    
                    '<div class="col-md-3 p-10" style="padding-top:10px">' +
                    '<div class="dropdown">' +
                    '<button class="btnV" id="idOne">Dropdown</button>' +
                    '<div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">' +
                    '<br>Select size' +
                    '<select id="Vsel">' +
                    '<option selected>256x256</option>' +
                    '<option>512x512</option>' +
                    '<option>1024x1024</option>' +
                    '</select>' +
                    '<br>Enter quantity' +
                    '<input type="number" id="Vquantity" value="1" min="1" max="10" />' +
                    '<br>' +
                    '<button id="' + btnID + '" >Generate</button>' +
                    '</div>' +
                    '</div>' +
                    '<img class="p-10" id="GenImg" src = "' + this.url + '">' +
                    '</div>');
            });
        });
    });

$(document.body).on('click', '[id^=VarBtn]', function () {
    var dropdown = $(this).closest('.dropdown-content');
    var input = {};
    input.size = dropdown.find('#Vsel').val();
    input.quantity = parseInt(dropdown.find('#Vquantity').val());
    // do something with input
});
```

Comment: "Try this" is rarely useful. You should add some commentary or explanation to your answer to show what code you've changed/added and why.

Comment: Ok sorry for the short description, I'll use your advice in the future @Andy !

Comment: You can edit your answer and use the advice here.